# SVG - ECG like graph

Tags: android

Have a requirement that is to render ECG when a medical device is connected to a android device. Now there is a lot of info about this on SO and it has left me confused.. :-|....What I would want to know is that is it possible in Android device running version 2.2? How do I go about it.
Any help or ideas to point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

The quick answer is yes, it's entirely possible on Android 2.2+ (e.g. see [Frequensee](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.DanielBach.FrequenSee)).

There are several approaches to drawing real-time graphs but you are more than likely going to end up having to use OpenGLES to get the best performance/quality. OpenGLES 1.0 is sufficient for an ECG type graph if you don't feel like wading through OpenGLES 2.0 shading language and/or also want to support devices which don't support OpenGLES 2.0

Comment: Hmmm...tonys you make much more sense...If u could outline the steps to be followed...The developer of FrequenSee, Mr Daniel Bach, says he used native code using OpenGLES 2.0..what does it mean? Sorry for all the trouble...i m kind of new to Android devvelopment... I do want to use OpenGLES 1.0 as you say it is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can draw graphs usin aFreeChart library for more details/Code/Jar file/Apk chk this site

http://code.google.com/p/afreechart/

Comment: Hello Krishna, by the first looks of it, it renders only charts that have plotted information...ECG wont have plotted info but would give you live data that needs to be plotted and then rendered...Am I correct?

Comment: And I downloaded the app, but does not seem to support the vector drawable, eventhough it is found in the screenshot!!!

Comment: Install demo app on your device there are number of charts go through them you will definitely find your problems solution.

Comment: I installed the demo app....went through it also.....cant find support for Vector graphics.....may be i am missing something, if u cud guide me?